# How to strip comments in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, auth0

I have multiple files that start with comments like:

```
/*
 * @title Force email verification
 * @overview Only allow access to users with verified emails.
 * @gallery true
 * @category access control
 *
 * This rule will only allow access users that have verified their emails.
 *
 * > Note: It might be a better UX to make this verification from your application.
 *
 * If you are using [Lock](https://auth0.com/docs/lock), the default behavior is to log in a user immediately after they have signed up.
 * To prevent this from immediately displaying an error to the user, you can pass the following option to `lock.show()` or similar: `loginAfterSignup: false`.
 *
 * If you are using [auth0.js](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js), the equivalent option is `auto_login: false`.
 *
 */
//jshint -W025
function (user, context, callback) {
  if (!user.email_verified) {
    return callback(new UnauthorizedError('Please verify your email before logging in.'));
  } else {
    return callback(null, user, context);
  }
}
```

All files contains two types of comments i.e `/**/` and `//` Now I am reading this file in my javascript code and want to remove comments and get the actual code in the variable e.g

```
function (user, context, callback) {
  if (!user.email_verified) {
    return callback(new UnauthorizedError('Please verify your email before logging in.'));
  } else {
    return callback(null, user, context);
  }
}
```

I have tried using strip-comments and parse-comments npm but none of these work. Here is the code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const strip = require('strip-comments');
module.exports = function (ruleFileName, globals, stubs) {
    globals = globals || {};
    stubs = stubs || {};
    const fileName = path.join(__dirname, '../src/rules', ruleFileName + '.js');
    const data = fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf8');
    const code = strip(data);
    console.log(code);
    return compile(code, globals, stubs);
}
```

and with parse-comments I tried like:

```
const parsed = parseComments(data)[0];
const code = data.split('\n').slice(parsed.comment.end).join('\n').trim();
```

I think strip comment is not working because it takes string as an argument but fs.readFileSync doesn't return string. I have also tried `data.toString()`but that also didn't work. So how can I strip comments from the content? Is there any other solution?

Comment: check out this [link]https://github.com/jonschlinkert/strip-comments

Comment: already saw that, but it's not working as strip-comments takes string as an argument

Comment: If you use Komodo Edit, you can use a RegEx across multiple files. `cntrl+h`.

Comment: "*but fs.readFileSync doesn't return string*" - actually, [it *does* return a string](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) since you pass an encoding option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use regx to replace `/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|([^:]|^)\/\/.*$/gm`

```
   var Text = `/*
     * @title Force email verification
     * @overview Only allow access to users with verified emails.
     * @gallery true
     * @category access control
     *
     * This rule will only allow access users that have verified their emails.
     *
     * > Note: It might be a better UX to make this verification from your application.
     *
     * If you are using [Lock](https://auth0.com/docs/lock), the default behavior is to log in a user immediately after they have signed up.
     * To prevent this from immediately displaying an error to the user, you can pass the following option to "lock.show()" or similar: "loginAfterSignup: false".
     *
     * If you are using [auth0.js](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js), the equivalent option is "auto_login: false".
     *
     */
    //jshint -W025
    function (user, context, callback) {
      if (!user.email_verified) {
        return callback(new UnauthorizedError('Please verify your email before logging in.'));
      } else {
        return callback(null, user, context);
      }
    }`

     console.log(Text.replace(/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|([^:]|^)\/\/.*$/gm,''))
```

like this
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eQKrWP

Comment: thanks, it works but I had to add .trim() in the end to mke it work.i.e data.replace(/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|([^:]|^)\/\/.*$/gm, '').trim()